# Push method dont push the elements

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello in the code below all worke but the values aren't pushed in the array, know why ? :

```js
app.get("/overview", (req,res)=>{
    const email = "jack.pro.official@gmail.com"

    const getFiles = (directoryPath) => {
        const files = new Array();
        const directories = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath);
        
        for (const directory of directories) {
            const fullPath = path.join(directoryPath, directory);
            if (fs.existsSync(fullPath) && fs.statSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
                const subFiles = getFiles(fullPath);
                files.push(...subFiles);
            } else {
                files.push(fullPath);
            }
        }

        return files;
    };

    const files = getFiles('./ToDoLists/jack.pro.official@gmail.com/');
    const names = new Array();

    files.forEach((fileName) => {
        fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
          const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
          const name = parsedData.toDoListName;
          names.push(name)
        });
    });
    
    return res.json(names)
})
```

i need the values to be pushed into the array

Comment: [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) does not accept callback. Simply use `const data = readFileSync(fileName, "utf8"); const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);//...rest`

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests `readFileSync` is not asynchronous, so it returns the data rather than calling a callback function. So change your loop to:

```
const names = files.map((fileName) => {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8');
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  return parsedData.toDoListName;
});
```

Comment: Does it work with fs.readFile() sympli ?

Comment: If you do that, the order of the results will be unpredictable, because asynchronous callbacks aren't executed in the same order as the files you're looping over.

Comment: Also, `return res.json(names)` won't wait for the callbacks, so you'll return an empty array. You'd have to convert the code to use Promises, then you can wait for them all with `Promise.all()`.